# Can I group columns of my database into an array when outputting as JSON?

Tags: json, database, sequelize.js

I have multiple dates that are the same and I want to group the dates so I have an array of `time` and `bg_reading` because there will be multiple values for the same date. This is what my JSON is spitting out.

```
`[
  {
    "date": "2016-03-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "22:03:54",
    "bg_reading": 9.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "12:05:56",
    "bg_reading": 12.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "01:17:06",
    "bg_reading": 15.5
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "06:27:42",
    "bg_reading": 17.1
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "06:19:21",
    "bg_reading": 27.6
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "17:03:27",
    "bg_reading": 14.5
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "22:03:54",
    "bg_reading": 9.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "12:05:56",
    "bg_reading": 12.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "01:17:06",
    "bg_reading": 15.5
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "06:27:42",
    "bg_reading": 17.1
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "06:19:21",
    "bg_reading": 27.6
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "17:03:27",
    "bg_reading": 14.5
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "22:03:54",
    "bg_reading": 9.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "12:05:56",
    "bg_reading": 12.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "01:17:06",
    "bg_reading": 15.5
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "06:27:42",
    "bg_reading": 17.1
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "06:19:21",
    "bg_reading": 27.6
  },
  {enter code here
    "date": "2016-03-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": "17:03:27",
    "bg_reading": 14.5
  }
]`
```

I was hoping to have it something like this:

```
`[
  {
    "date": "2016-03-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "time": ["05:22:33", "09:33:10", "15:01:34", "18:03:34", "21:34:09"],
    "bg_reading": [9.4, 6.3, 13.3, 6.8, 7.3]
  }...
]`
```

But right now I have no idea why the heck there are so many repeating values and why there are multiple dates. This is how I attempted to query it on Sequelise.

```
`  Log.findAll({
    where: {
      bg_reading: {gt: 0}
    },
    attributes: ['date', 'time', 'bg_reading'],
    group: 'date',
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    res.send(data)
  })
`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - it is indeed weird that you get multiple entries for the same date. My guess would be that the dates actually differ in time of day, even though it doesn't look like that. Try extracting the date part. Since you haven't specified the SQL dialect I'll give examples in psql, but you should be able to find similar in mysql etc.

```
 group: 'date_trunc('day', date)'
```

Will group by the date part only (it truncates the datetime down to day so that hour, minutes, seconds etc. is 0)

In order to get arrays for time and bg_reading you need to select it as such - in pg that function is called `array_agg` (`group_concat` in mysql)

```
attributes: [sequelize.fn('array_agg', sequelize.col('time')) ...],
```